# `fetch`, work with mode `no-cors` does not call the promise.then callback

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is my code snippet:

```
const url = util.API + '/ip/ip2addr' + `?ip=${this.state.ip}&key=${util.appKey}`;

 fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
     //does not call this callback
     this.setState({res: data.result});
 }).catch(err => {

 });
```

I saw the response, but not call the `promise.then` method, why? how can I get the response data?

It seems third-party api do not support `CORS`, so, my think is to write a node server.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(extended: true)); 

app.get('/ip/ip2addr', (req, res) => {
    const url = util.API + '/ip/ip2addr' + `?ip=${ip}&key=${appKey}`;

    request
    .get({url}, (err, response, body) => {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.json(body);
        }
    })
```

});

```
app.listen(port, err => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(`Server is listen on port ${port}`);
});
```

After search and read some articles, I think `webpack-dev-server` proxy settings will solve this problem too.

Comment: Is there an error caught?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `{mode: 'no-cors'}`

Comment: @MattWay Yes, I catch a error `Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @JaromandaX `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.com:3002' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`  I call a third party API, how to solve that?

Comment: looks like your API doesn't produce valid json

Comment: oh, you're using 'no-cors' to try and get around a server that doesn't allow CORS requests - oh, if only the web were that easy to hack :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it seems to be. How can I solve that ? I think i have to use `node` server to make request to third party api, and my web request my `node` server? I want to use `http://localhost` server to call third party api.

Comment: @MattWay `Exception
:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at SyntaxError (native) at http://localhost:3002/1.chunk.js:49:29`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) has an  explanation why your code doesn't work:

> `no-cors` — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not add or override any headers except for these. **In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response.** This ensures that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics of the Web and prevents security and privacy issues arising from leaking data across domains.

Basically, you a `no-cors` request results in an *opaque* response, that which JavaScript code cannot read. You're allowed to make the request, but you still can't circument CORS.

While you can't read from these responses, one use case for `no-cors` is service workers, which may intercept want to intercept requests from different origins (for instance, when an `<img />` loads), e.g., for caching. (Jake Archibald explains a bit about this [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/#no-cors-and-opaque-responses))

Comment: Yes, it seems to be. How can I solve that ? I think i have to use node server to make request to third party api, because `node` have no `CORS` problem and browser have.  And, my web app request my node server? I want to use http://localhost server to call third party api

Comment: @novaline If the third-party server does support CORS, use that. Otherwise, you just have to proxy your requests through a server that *does* support CORS, AFAIK there's pretty much no way around that.

Comment: oh, I start to get the point. But, actually, Can you give me some ways to do that? I know `node` , I use `charles`, but I do not know `nginx`. Does `Charles` can proxy my request ?

Comment: @novaline If you're comfortable sending your requests through a third party, something like https://crossorigin.me/ should be fine (especially for testing). It's also [open source](https://github.com/technoboy10/crossorigin.me), so you could probably set up your own clone if you want to have your own server (e.g., in case that site is shut down for some reason).